# Blinking/Flashing UIView depending on bit in array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to blink iPhone screen (background color of UIView) depending on bit in array `[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]` (black - white its 1) or (white - black its 0).

But I can't figure out how to use loops and conditions in animation.

**Not working code**

```
Byte u = 65; 
self.myBlock.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

int i = 0;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:8.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];


if (((u >> i) & 1) == 1) {
    self.myBlock.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.myBlock.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    printf("1");
} else {
    self.myBlock.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.myBlock.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    printf("0");
}
i++; // how it can be increased ?


[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you expand your question, describing what goes wrong when you try the code you say isn't working?

Comment: Just learning how to use loops and conditions in animation. In my code var i  is not increasing. Compiler doing all the calculations and in UIview I see only final result of it. 
And I thought that block
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
work like loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for the swift but converting to objective-c should be trivial. You can achieve your desired functionality using a recursive function like this.

We declare our array:

```
let colors = [0,1,1,0,1,1,0]
```

Our recursive function would look like this:

```
/**
     Cyle the background color based on bit array.

     - parameter indicies: An array where the first item is our start index of color array. Second item is the number of times we want the animation to iterate through completely.
     */
    func cycleColors(indicies: [Int]) {

        // Our current index in the colors array
        var currentArrayIndex = indicies[0]

        // Our current index in number of full cycles through the color array we've completed
        var fullInterations   = indicies[1]

        // We cycle through our number of full iterations until we reach 0, then we escape. This will break the recusive function.
        if (fullInterations == 0) {
            return
        }

        // Change the colors based on the array value
        if (colors[currentArrayIndex] == 0) {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
        else if (colors[currentArrayIndex] == 1) {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }

        // Set our next index. Basically if the currentArrayIndex is at the end of our array, we reset it to 0 and subtract from the number of full iterations we've done. Otherwise we increment the array index
        if (currentArrayIndex == colors.count - 1) {
            currentArrayIndex = 0
            fullInterations -= 1
        }
        else {
            currentArrayIndex += 1
        }

        // Call our function recursively
        performSelector(#selector(ViewController.cycleColors(_:)), withObject: [currentArrayIndex, fullInterations], afterDelay: 0.1)
    }
```

We call the function like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // We want to start at our first color and iterate through 5 times
    cycleColors([0, 5])
}
```